24.04 desktop install to USB/SSD on Raspberry Pi 4B fails [Solved]
Edit.1: I am experiencing this issue with RpiOS with H/W that worked without difficulty previously. At present I do not believe this is an Ubuntu issue.
Edit,2: I was able to resolve the issue by performing a secure erase on the SSD. Apparently some artifact from a previous install (partitioning) was preventing the process that expands the root filesystem from completing. I was unable to reproduce the issue and will not be able to file a bug report (which would be filed against RpiOS anyway.)
Good morning,
I'd like to run Ubuntu 24.04 from a USB connected SSD on a Raspberry Pi 4B. I've followed the instructions which indicate to use the Imager to install the image to the media and then boot. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#2-prepare-the-sd-card I've examined the page https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#4-optional-boot-from-usb-with-an-external-ssd and meet the criteria there. (This particular Pi can boot RpiOS and Debian from a USB/SSD and I have previously run Ubuntu from SSD following the instructions at https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS%20for%20Raspberry%20Pi.html but I prefer a plain installation at this time.)
The system comes up and I see the splash screen with the spinner. Eventually I'm presented with an (initramfs) prompt. Hitting <ctrl>D results in a kernel panic. Power cycling and getting bnack to the (initramfs) prompt and typing reboot seems to do nothing. this time <ctrl>D produces a message that the root filesystem could not be mounted.
Examining the SSD in another PC, I can see that the root filesystem has been expanded but there seems not to be a filesystem there. blkid /dev/sda2 lists nothing. cmdline.txt in the boot partition indicates that the root partition is root-LABEL=writable and the root partition was so labelled following imaging. It seems like the first boot processing broke after/during resizing the partition.
Any easy fix for this? It seems like I should label the partition and recreate the filesystem with existing contents but I cannot see a way to recreate the filesystem with the existing contents intact.
Seems like a bug and I am not familiar enough with Ubuntu to know where to look for this. It seems unlikely that I'm the first to encounter this problem. Launchpad seems like the place to look but it seems focused on packages and I don't know which package would be involved with first boot processing.
Thanks!
Edit.0: I can install to SD card and have a running system. I copied the SD card to the SSD and when trying to boot that, it still winds up in an (initramfs) prompt. I can see that the uas and usb_storage modules are loaded and I can mount the boot and root partitions on the SSD and view contents. The (initramfs) warning is
ALERT! LABEL=writable does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

Examining the SSD in another PC I can confirm that the writable partition no longer exists. It did when I copied the image from the SD card.
